# Get only properties of an instance

Tags: python, properties, decorator

I was wondering if there's a way in Python(2.6) to get only the name of the properties an instance has.

Let's say I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):   
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        print "Setting x to %s" % (value)
        try:
            self._x = int(value)
        except ValueError:
            self._x = None



#main (test area)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = MyClass()
    a.x = "5"
    print str(a.x)
    print "Vars: %s" %vars(a)   
    print "Dir: %s" %dir(a)
```

Which outputs:

```
Vars: {'_x': 5}
Dir: ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_x', 'x']
```

Is there a similar command to "vars" or "dir" or so that would give me "x" only?

If not, what do you guys recommend to do? Walk the "vars" keys and remove the "_" that appears in front of "_x"?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
def iter_properties_of_class(cls):
    for varname in vars(cls):
        value = getattr(cls, varname)
        if isinstance(value, property):
            yield varname

def properties(inst):
    result = {}
    for cls in inst.__class__.mro():
        for varname in iter_properties_of_class(cls):
            result[varname] = getattr(inst, varname)
    return result

>>> a = MyClass()
>>> a.x = 5
Setting x to 5
>>> properties(a)
{'x': 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instances don't have properties. They are [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors), so they have to be in the **class** to work. `vars(MyClass)` should return it.

```
class MyClass(object):
    @property
    def x(self):
        pass

print vars(MyClass).keys()
```

prints

```
['__module__', '__dict__', 'x', '__weakref__', '__doc__']
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!
Well... at least the example I tried, it's returning "_x", but I'd like to get "x" (somehow)

Comment: @BorrajaX: What? no, it returns `x` not `_x`. Check my example.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to what @nosklo's posted, for his quickness.

Descriptors are how properties are implemented.

```
>>> o = MyClass()
>>> print type(o.x)
<type 'NoneType'>
>>> print type(MyClass.x)
<type 'property'>
```